AnyLogic conditional transition in statechart
I want the transition to be happened based on the start time condition. Each Person agent has its own start time as a parameter read from excel data. Start time is of data type double> Let say a Person's start time is 10.5, I want when the simulation run time is 10.5 mins, this person will move from one state to another. What I tried is shown in attached pic, but I don't see any movement of the agent. Simulation time unit is minute.

This question is similar to: Event triggered by condition. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yeah, pls always first search for your problem. In a nutshell: do not use conditional transitions ever. You can always replace them with a msg-based setup. Less error-prone and more computationally efficient. Win-win
